# Android : How to play multiple mp3 tracks simultaneously

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, mp3

In the application, songs will have been split into multiple tracks, one track per instrument.

I need to be able to play all the tracks simultaneously.

I have seen that MediaPlayer is not able to do this, indeed having 5 to 10 separate tracks would cause too much latency.

SoundPool states that it is specifically for short sounds and so is inappropriate for this.

It would appear that AudioTrack would be the answer, but that requires decoding each mp3 into pcm data before playing it.

So, here are my questions -

1. Even though I have not found any, do any tutorials exist demonstrating how to achieve this ?
2. Can anyone advise on how to play multiple audiotracks simultaneously ?
3. Are there any existing examples on how to decode mp3 files using the NDK ?

Comment: [android.media.MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) ?

Comment: MediaCodec would be good if there was but one file to decode and play.  However, I am dealing with multiple files playing at the same time - which is why this has to be done in the NDK.

Comment: how NDK API differs from java when it comes to data source? you mean `AMediaExtractor_*` stuff?

Comment: Not really. I am basing my comments on two articles - http://mindtherobot.com/blog/624/android-audio-play-an-mp3-file-on-an-audiotrack/ - and Google IO 2016 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2ZDp-eNrh4